# Two state system periodic chain with nearest neighbour exclusion

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a chain of $N$ distinguishable sites each of which can be in one of two possible states, $1$ or $0$. Also the chain is closed, i.e. the last element is adjacent to the first. What is the total number of possible states of the system, under the condition that no pair of adjacent sites can be simultaneously in state $1$?

Examples:

$1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0$  - Valid

$0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 $ - Not valid

$1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 $ - Not valid

Comment: You can rephrase the question - a 1 must be followed by a zero so starting at the first entry you can fill out a single space with 0 or two spaces with 10. So try counting the ways you can divide n spaces into singlets and doublets, then try to account for the end point. If you start with a single space you may end with a 0 or a 1, starting with a 10 you must end with a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the well-known Lucas numbers; see [A000204 in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000204) for plenty of references.